# how to detect point on/around a line (with some offset)

Tags: math, geometry, 2d, graphic

Drawn a line from a point A to point B. Let d be offset. Let C be point to be tested.

I am going to do a kind of hit testing around the line with offset.

How can i do the hit testing around the line with the given offset.

Ex: A = (10,10), B (30,30), offset = 2. choose C as any point. Please Refer the image in the link please.

http://s10.postimg.org/6by2dzvax/reference.png

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you give the point an offset, than it's no more a **point to line** collision. Rather it's **rectangle to line** collision.

Comment: i didnt mention my actual requirement before. Now i edited.

Comment: Thanks. FYI.. i just updated direct link for image. http://s10.postimg.org/6by2dzvax/reference.png

Comment: There is a misunderstanding, this is indeed a point/line collision problem with offset (or call it point inside rectangle). The figure is a little misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Find offset for C.
e.g. dx1 and dy1. If dy1/dx1=dy/dx then your C hits the line.
For segment you should also check if whether dx1 < dx or dy1 < dy.

Comment: Thanks jokey, i didnt mention my actual requirement before. Now i edited.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want to check if that point `C` is inside a certain rectangle, with dimensions `2*d` and `|A-B|+2*d`.  
 You need to represent the line as `u*x+v*y+w=0`, this can be accomplished by

```
u = A.y-B.y
v = B.x-A.x
w = A.x*B.y - A.y * B.x
```

Then the (signed) distance of `C` from that line would be

```
d = (u*C.x + v*C.y +w) / sqrt( u*u+v*v)
```

You compare `abs(d)` to your offset.

The next step would be to check the position of `C` in the direction of the line.  To that end you consider the orthogonal line `u2*x+v2*y+w2=0` with

```
u2 = v
v2 = -u
w2 = -u2*(A.x+B.x)/2 - v2*(A.y+B.y)/2
```

and the distance

```
d2 = (u2 * C.x + v2 * C.y + w2 ) / sqrt( u2*u2+v2*v2 )
```

This distance must be compared to something like the length of the line+offset:

```
abs(d2) < |A-B| / 2 + offset
```

Comment: Thanks.. I checked the point C(45,45) against the line AB A(15, 15), B(60,60), offset = 2. it gives incorrect answer. i.e it gives C(45,45) is not on the line (rectangle bounds). but the point C(45,45) lies on line AB.

Comment: No, it works well.  In this case you get `u=-45`, `v=45`, `w=0`, `d=0`, `u2=45`, `v2=45`, `w2=-3375`, `d2=10.6`, `|A-B|=63.6`.  The result is well within the limits.

Comment: yes, it works. sorry i might be missed some * or / when i calculate before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A convenient trick is to rotate and translate the plane in such a way that the segment `AB` maps to the segment `(0, 0)-(0, L)` (just like on the image), `L` being the segment length.

If you apply the same transform to `C`, then it a very simple matter to test inclusion in the rectangle.

That useful transform is given by:

```
x = ((X - XA).(XB - XA) + (Y - YA).(YB - YA)) / L
y = ((X - XA).(YB - YA) - (Y - YA).(XB - XA)) / L
```

Comment: Thanks. As i am not good in matrix rotation/translation, please give some guide to do rotate/translate the plan. Any reference link or programming code will help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this function to count the shortest distance of the point to the line. If the distance is <= offset, then that point is hitting the line.

```
    private double pointDistanceToLine(PointF line1, PointF line2, PointF pt) 
    { 
        var isValid = false;

        PointF r = new PointF(); 
        if (line1.Y == line2.Y && line1.X == line2.X) 
            line1.Y -= 0.00001f;

        double U = ((pt.Y - line1.Y ) * (line2.Y - line1.Y )) + ((pt.X - line1.X) * (line2.X - line1.X));

        double Udenom = Math.Pow(line2.Y - line1.Y , 2) + Math.Pow(line2.X - line1.X, 2);

        U /= Udenom;

        r.Y = (float)(line1.Y + (U * (line2.Y - line1.Y ))); r.X = (float)(line1.X + (U * (line2.X - line1.X)));

        double minX, maxX, minY , maxY ;

        minX = Math.Min(line1.Y , line2.Y ); 
        maxX = Math.Max(line1.Y , line2.Y );

        minY = Math.Min(line1.X, line2.X); 
        maxY = Math.Max(line1.X, line2.X);

        isValid = (r.Y >= minX && r.Y <= maxX) && (r.X >= minY && r.X <= maxY );

        //return isValid ? r : null; 
        if (isValid) 
        { 
            double result = Math.Pow((pt.X - r.X), 2) + Math.Pow((pt.Y - r.Y), 2); 
            result = Math.Sqrt(result); 
            return result; 
        } 
        else { 
            double result1 = Math.Pow((pt.X - line1.X), 2) + Math.Pow((pt.Y - line1.Y), 2); 
            result1 = Math.Sqrt(result1); 
            double result2 = Math.Pow((pt.X - line2.X), 2) + Math.Pow((pt.Y - line2.Y), 2); 
            result2 = Math.Sqrt(result2);

            return Math.Min(result1, result2); 
        } 
    }
```